# Simple 3D barplot of a 2D histogram after PCA

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I already read some the question that I could find here or elsewhere. I wrote the code using other questions available on **stackoverflow** but still it doesn't work sometimes. There are three types of problems that might occur. I write the code here first and then will list the problems:

```
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.subplot(111,projection='3d')
sample=np.asarray(sample)
result=PCA(sample)
hist, xedges, yedges =np.histogram2d(result.Y[:,0],result.Y[:,1])
x_data, y_data = np.meshgrid( np.arange(hist.shape[1]),np.arange(hist.shape[0]) )        
x_data = x_data.flatten()
y_data = y_data.flatten()
z_data = hist.flatten()
ax.bar3d( x_data,y_data,np.zeros(len(z_data)),1, 1, z_data )
fig.tight_layout()   
fig.savefig('3Dhist.eps')
plt.show()
```

1- First problem is the following error:

```
LinAlgError: SVD did not converge 
     97 
     98 def _raise_linalgerror_svd_nonconvergence(err, flag):
---> 99     raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge")
    100 
    101 def get_linalg_error_extobj(callback):

LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

And it rises when all of my vectors share one equal coordinate, i.e. they already lie on the same plane. Obviously a PCA is still possible with a unique answer but it gives the above error. To test it you can set sample to:

```
sample=[[ 0.,  0.2, 0. ],
 [ 0.4, 0.2, 0. ],
 [ 0.4, 0.4, 0. ],
 [ 0.,  0.2, 0. ],
 [ 0.6, 0.2, 0. ]]
```

2-**(Semi-Solved: See the answers section.)** The second problem is the following warning:

```
/Users/****/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py:1673: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  for n in normals])
/Users/****/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:394: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  if (c.ravel() > 1).any() or (c.ravel() < 0).any():
/Users/****/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:394: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  if (c.ravel() > 1).any() or (c.ravel() < 0).any():
```

I don't know the reason of this warning but this rises usually on large samples that I generate from my distribution.

3-3rd problem is that I cannot save it in any other format than `.png` or otherwise it doesn't work. To clarify the array I am using is a `numpy.float64`.

Answer (score 0):

I already find the answer for the second issue for the people who are interested. It seems that 3D plotting in matplotlib has serious issues. You can check here:
[matplotlib bar3d clipping problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602660/matplotlib-bar3d-clipping-problems)